# Safari crashed often

Tags: macos, safari, web, crash

My safari crashed recently with the following log. What's the problem and what should I do? I have tried to restart my mac but useless. Thanks in advance!

```
Process:         Safari [419]
Path:            /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
Identifier:      com.apple.Safari
Version:         5.0.5 (6533.21.1)
Build Info:      WebBrowser-75332101~6
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [103]

Date/Time:       2012-08-04 15:40:27.264 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          9013 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           3
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  8935 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   3
Anonymous UUID:                      00799C43-68AE-4021-B3CF-3E99073F1C5B

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff830dd386 WebCore::QualifiedName::deref() + 22
1   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff831b6da9 WTF::Vector<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::Attribute>, 0ul>::shrink(unsigned long) + 153
2   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff83165cd5 WTF::Vector<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::Attribute>, 0ul>::shrinkCapacity(unsigned long) + 197
3   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8314e509 WebCore::Element::~Element() + 57
4   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8328ef5e WebCore::HTMLDivElement::~HTMLDivElement() + 62
5   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8314e2cc void WebCore::removeAllChildrenInContainer<WebCore::Node, WebCore::ContainerNode>(WebCore::ContainerNode*) + 76
6   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8314e0d1 WebCore::Document::removedLastRef() + 225
7   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8310f3e2 WebCore::Event::~Event() + 130
8   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff8328fda0 WebCore::JSEvent::~JSEvent() + 240
9   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff885e49a1 JSC::Heap::sweep() + 257
10  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff885e0dfb JSC::Heap::collectAllGarbage() + 75
11  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff832cb255 WebCore::collect(void*) + 21
12  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff83199687 WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 151
13  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff83a40765 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 53
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000100b3fbe8 __CFRunLoopRun + 6488
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000100b3ddbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff88b597ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff88b595f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 310
18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff88b594ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88e8feb2 _DPSNextEvent + 708
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88e8f801 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
21  com.apple.Safari                0x0000000100015ffa 0x100000000 + 90106
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88e5568f -[NSApplication run] + 395
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88e4e3b0 NSApplicationMain + 364
24  com.apple.Safari                0x0000000100009f1c 0x100000000 + 40732
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

- open the **Finder**, from the Finder menu bar click `Go > Go to Folder`.
- Type and hit **Go**:      `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist`
- `com.apple.Safari.plist` move this file from the Preferences folder
  to anywhere else.
- Relaunch Safari. **If Safari runs good**, move the **.plist file to the
  Trash**. **If not**, move it **back to the Preferences** folder of Safari.

Comment: com.apple.Safari.plist is not there. Don't know why.

Comment: I find it now. let me try.

Comment: Still crashed after the file is deleted.

Comment: oh.. try to re-install `"Webkit"`, which is supported the browsing engine like Safari